# In Xamarin.Forms, do I need to remove event handlers from views?

Tags: event-handling, xamarin.forms

If I set an event handler with code, do I need to remove the event handler as well?
In order to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: not unless you want to stop listening while the object is live.

Comment: yes you need to always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a best practice to remove the event handlers when you navigate away from the current view.

You can remove your handlers in `OnDisappearing` method

Comment: Could you show us how to do it please? Thanks.